# Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on string

Tags: php

Não consigo encontrar o erro que está aparecendo no meu banco-produto. Alguém poderia me ajudar a encontrar? Agradeco de antemão.

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on string in         C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.19-0\apache2\htdocs\beladuquesa\sys\banco-produto.php on line 85
```

esta é a função alteraProduto:

```
    function alteraProduto($conexao, $produto) {


echo ("* inicio funcao alteraProduto * "); //Aviso de teste

81)$query = "update produtos set nome = '{$produto->getNome()}',
82)codigo = {$produto->getCodigo()},
83)preco = {$produto->getPreco()},
84)descricao = '{$produto->getDescricao()}',
85)categoria_id = {$produto->getCategoria()->getId()},
86)cor_id = {$produto->getCor()->getId()},
87)tamanho_id = {$produto->getTamanho()->getId()} where id = 88)'{$produto->getId()}'";**

return mysqli_query($this->conexao, $query);

echo ($query); //Aviso de teste
}
```

Este é o teste que fiz do que está vindo do altera-produto:

```
* inicio alteração * * Envia para Banco Produto * array(8) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["codigo"]=> string(2) "12" ["nome"]=> string(13) "Vestido Paula" ["preco"]=> string(6) "100.00" ["descricao"]=> string(20) "Vestido em Tricoline" ["cor_id"]=> string(2) "20" ["tamanho_id"]=> string(1) "5" ["categoria_id"]=> string(1) "2" } * inicio funcao alteraProduto *
```

Este é o arquivo altera-produto:

```
    <?php
require_once 'conecta.php';
require_once 'banco-produto.php';
require_once 'banco-cor.php';
require_once 'banco-tamanho.php';
require_once 'banco-categoria.php';
require_once 'produto.php';
require_once 'cor.php';
require_once 'tamanho.php';
require_once 'categoria.php';


$produto = new Produto();
echo ("* inicio alteração * "); //Aviso de teste
$produto->setId( $_POST['id'] );
$produto->setCodigo( $_POST["codigo"]) ;
$produto->setNome( $_POST["nome"]);
$produto->setPreco( $_POST["preco"]);
$produto->setDescricao( $_POST["descricao"]);
$produto->setCor(new Cor());
$produto->setCor( $_POST["cor_id"]);
$produto->setTamanho(new Tamanho());
$produto->setTamanho( $_POST["tamanho_id"]);
$produto->setCategoria(new Categoria());
$produto->setCategoria( $_POST["categoria_id"]);
echo ("* Envia para Banco Produto * "); //Aviso de teste
var_dump($_POST);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu código está definindo duas vezes a categoria, uma como um objeto e outra como o conteúdo de `$_POST["categoria_id"]`.

Tente mudar sua rotina de altera-produto para ficar assim:

```
$produto->setCategoria(new Categoria());
$produto->getCategoria()->setId( $_POST["categoria_id"]);
echo ("* Envia para Banco Produto * "); //Aviso de teste
```

Note que você tem esse mesmo problema com a propriedade `Tamanho`. Você cria um objeto e logo em seguida seta o conteúdo de `$_POST["tamanho_id"]`.

Comment: Muito obrigado Hertel na mosca!!! Resolvido.

Comment: De nada. Se tiver mais problemas abra uma nova pergunta.